# Connecting C# to a remote MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect a C# application to my MySQL database located in a remote server. When I try to execute this simple program, I get the following error: `sqlException was unhandled`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=student_abdo;password=XXXXXX;server=178.239.167.XXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=student_sms;connection timeout=30");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE `sms` SET `id`=23 WHERE `sms`='hi'",con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're getting an exception, and not catching it with a try/catch block. Probably the connection's failing, throwing that unhandled exception. Never assume a database operation succeeds, especially with a remote database. **always** have error handling in place.

Comment: Marc, that's definitely a good point, but the bigger problem is that he's using the wrong driver.

Answer (score 3):

The SqlClient namespace is for connecting to Microsoft SqlServer databases. If you want to work with MySql, you'll need to find an ADO.NET implementation (3rd party) or determine if there is a way to make it work with OleDb/Odbc.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, MySql provides [its own ADO.NET driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html) for getting the job done.

Comment: using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Answer (score 0):

As Brian pointed out, you are using the wrong provider. Also, your connection string is wrong. It should read

```
"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
```

You can reference [this site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for all of the different connection string types for mysql

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)  is what you need to download

Keep in mind that Classes for working with MySql in .NET are mostley the same as working with MSSQL with exception that they have My... prefix

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("userid=student_abdo;password=XXXXXX;server=178.239.167.XXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=student_sms;connection timeout=30");
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `sms` SET `id`=23 WHERE `sms`='hi'",con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you know what is forms of connect string and then established the connection with the database.

```
<a href="http://www.technomakes.net/2016/10/bb-rec-screen-recorder-iOS.html">bb rec</a>

private void btnretrive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=world;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from world;",conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    conn.Close();
}
```